# apply max to varying-dimension subsets of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

For a dataframe with an indexed column with repeated indexes, I'm trying to get the maximum value found in a different column, by index, and assign it to a third column, so that for any given row, we can see the maximum value found in any row with the same index.
I'm doing this over a very large data set and would like it to be vectorized if possible. For now, I can't get it to work at all

```
multiindexDF = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4],[5,6,7,10,15,11,25,89]]).transpose()
multiindexDF.columns = ['theIndex','theValue']
multiindexDF['maxValuePerIndex'] = 0
uniqueIndicies = multiindexDF['theIndex'].unique()
for i in uniqueIndices:
    matchingIndices = multiindexDF['theIndex'] == i
    maxValue = multiindexDF[matchingIndices == i]['theValue'].max()
    multiindexDF.loc[matchingIndices]['maxValuePerIndex'] = maxValue
```

This fails, telling me I should use .loc, when I'm already using it. Not sure what the error means, and not sure how I can fix this so I don't have to loop through everything so I can vectorize it instead

I'm looking for this

```
targetDF = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4],[5,6,10,7,15,11,25,89],[5,6,10,10,89,89,89,89]]).transpose()
targetDF
```

Comment: your code has some syntax errors, for example, `['theIndex'','theValue']` has an additional single quote

Comment: thanks. My original code didn't have that error, had to copy this over from another environment where I couldn't copy+paste into here. Is there another one I'm not seeing?

Comment: I stopped looking when I saw the first one and was too lazy to figure out the proper syntax for what I wanted to say :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a good case for groupby transform, this can get the maximum value per index group and transform them back onto their original index (rather than the grouped index):

```
multiindexDF['maxValuePerIndex'] = multiindexDF.groupby("theIndex")["theValue"].transform("max")
```

The reason you're getting the `SettingWithCopyWarning` is that in your `.loc` call you're taking a slice of a slice and setting the value there, see the two pair of square brackets in:

`multiindexDF.loc[matchingIndices]['maxValuePerIndex'] = maxValue`

So it tries to assign the value to the slice rather than the original DataFrame, you're doing a `.loc` and then another `[]` after it in a chain.

So using your original approach:

```
for i in uniqueIndices:
    matchingIndices = multiindexDF['theIndex'] == i
    maxValue = multiindexDF.loc[matchingIndices, 'theValue'].max()
    multiindexDF.loc[matchingIndices, 'maxValuePerIndex'] = maxValue
```

(Notice I've also changed the first `.loc` where you were incorrectly using the boolean index)

Comment: thanks! Any idea what was with the `.loc` error? [edit: he answered this after I made this comment]

Comment: @hedgedandlevered see my edits, it's a fairly common warning that can pop up, yours came from chaining the assignments