# Get result in matching category for max date by ID

Tags: python, pandas

For each ID, where the category matches, I want to find the row corresponding to the latest date, then return the entry in a different column.

Heres a MRE.

```
exFilterDF= pd.DataFrame([['1234','1234','1234','5678','5678','5678','9TJQ','9TJQ','9TJQ'],\
['good','ignore','good','good','good','ignore','good','good','ignore'],
['2017-11-10 12:40:07','2017-12-18 14:00:07','2017-12-13 17:40:07','2017-12-12 11:40:07','2017-12-19 16:40:07'\
,'2017-10-26 17:40:07','2017-12-13 17:40:07','2017-12-27 13:40:07','2017-10-12 13:40:07'],
['ReturnA','ReturnB','ReturnC','ReturnD','ReturnE','ReturnF','ReturnG','ReturnH','ReturnI']]).transpose()
exFilterDF.columns = ["ID","Category","Date","Result"]
exFilterDF
```

The resulting answer should be

```
answerDF= pd.DataFrame([['1234','5678','9TJQ'],['ReturnC','ReturnE','ReturnH']]).transpose()
answerDF.columns = ["ID","Result"]
answerDF
```

This will start off like the question I asked that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772699/apply-max-to-varying-dimension-subsets-of-pandas-dataframe)

Unfortunately, I can't just match to already found max(date)s, because, for example, in this set, `2017-12-13 17:40:07` is the correct date for the `ReturnC` row, but that same timestamp is in the `ReturnG` row (which should not be returned), so if we approach this by flagging "good dates" and then filtering on those, we'll get extra (wrong) results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `ID` among those values where `Category` is `good`, and use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to index the dataframe on the latest dates:

```
exFilterDF.Date = pd.to_datetime(exFilterDF.Date)
m = exFilterDF[exFilterDF.Category.eq('good')].groupby('ID').Date.idxmax()
exFilterDF.loc[m, ['ID', 'Result']]

    ID   Result
2  1234  ReturnC
4  5678  ReturnE
7  9TJQ  ReturnH
```